# Как заставить машину вывести панель выбора ОС?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-8, dual-boot

Суть проблемы: Есть 2 харда:

I :

1) 100Гб - windows 8

2) ...

II:

1) 100Гб - Linux Ubuntu 12.04

2) ...

Сейчас сижу из под линукса. Вопрос. Как сделать чтоб при старте машины появлась панель для выбора операционки? Сейчас насколько я понимаю будет стартовать та, хард которой в hard disk priority установлен выше. Не лазить же каждый раз в биос, чтоб войти в другую ОС.. Как быть?

зы. на соседнем форуме вопрос висит уже около часа. никто ничего не говорит. А ко мне через 2 часа манагеры в офис придут=\

**UPD1:**

Судя по всему не жить им вместе. 8-ка сразу грузится если может. А может если она на харде, который в boot priority выше. И если кому будет интересно, то:

Если ставить 2 этих системы на 1 хард:

1)  сначала винду потом linux, то грузится все равно винда, но не загружется - тупо умирает и все хотя и пытается выкрутиться сама из такой неловкой для неё ситуации, а к linux потом не подобраться.

2) если ставить сначала linux потом винду, то винда будет работать. к linux опять же не подобраться.

С разных хардов они знать друг друга не желают, хотя с 7-кой все было нормально на одном харде. Сначала ставил 7ку, потом рядом Ubuntu (только не 12.04, а 11.10 - но они вроде бы не особо отличаются, как и 8ка от 7ки) пока что я на этой стадии

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте grub-customizer на linux установить

Comment: можете поподробнее повествовать?

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/post/105851/

Answer (score -1):

В Ubuntu должно все уже быть настроено автоматом, `update-grub` должен увидеть второй винт и ШИНДОШS на нем и добавить опцию. См. `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` на предмет подобного:

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry "Windows 9 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)" --class windows --class os {
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ntfs
        set root='(hd0,msdos1)'
        search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
```

Если при загрузке не вылезает меню GRUB — возможно понадобится нажать Esc. Оно пишет подсказку, в любом случае, вроде бы.

Другой враиант — большинство современных BIOS'ов умеют по чему-то типа F8 выдавать меню выбора диска для загрузки.

Comment: На самом деле всё так и происходит как я говорил выше. Ничерта они не видят. ни винда линуху ни наоборот. Попробую по F8 сейчас.

==============

Бесполезно. Не судьба видимо

Comment: @Виталий Кустов Если у вас **award**, то F12, если и это не поможет, то внимательно смотрите что пишет биос при загрузке (там, где кол-во памяти и процессор) внизу экрана. Если вместо текста картинка, выключайте **splash screen**

Comment: @dword, большой тебе спасиб. Уже проще. Однако все равно хотелось бы нормальное окно выбора ОС. Попробую сейчас замутить так, как описано в вышеуказанной ссылке http://habrahabr.ru/post/105851/

Comment: Попробывал установил Grub. Менюшка появилась, но винда через неё не стартует. Поэтому пока что остается пользоваться методом .F12() =)

Comment: Смотрите в конфиг grub'а (образец отвечающего за ситуацию участка есть в моем ответе). Если не найдете в чем дело сами (в общем-то, все, пожалуй, что может быть неверным — неправильно указан диск, см. опции `root`) — обновите вопрос, запостив Ваш.